# Android Studio Emulator Crashing On Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio and am trying to create a log in screen which then opens an  inventory screen. The problem I am having is when I click Submit to the username and password, the app completely crashes. Right now, I am just working out how to organize the layout portion of things, but need to figure out how to get this transition to work. Any help would be great!

This is the main activity code:

```
package com.example.cs360projectone;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username, password;
    Button buttonLogIn, buttonRegister;;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
        buttonLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogIn);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(username.getText().toString().trim().length() <1 || password.getText().toString().trim().length() <1){
                    username.setError("You must enter a valid username and password");
                }
                else {
                    openInventory();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view1) {

                openRegisterScreen();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openRegisterScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openInventory() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InventoryScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the inventory screen code:

```
package com.example.cs360projectone;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class InventoryScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonSMS, buttonSignOut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_screen);

        buttonSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view1) {

                openSMSPermission();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openSMSPermission() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SMSPermissionScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the error from logcat when the button is pressed:

```
2022-08-03 16:54:09.037 8043-8043/com.example.cs360projectone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cs360projectone, PID: 8043
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cs360projectone/com.example.cs360projectone.InventoryScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.cs360projectone.InventoryScreen.onCreate(InventoryScreen.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2022-08-03 16:54:09.062 8043-8043/com.example.cs360projectone I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8043 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the SMS button in the InventoryScreen onCreate method the same way you did with the other buttons in MainActivity.

This means doing a

```
buttonSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSMS);
```

**before** setting up an onClickListener.

Comment: That was definitely the problem. I've been working on this too long...thank you!!